# Twilio: Responding to user input with multiple distinct messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on a twilio-programable-sms chatbot that needs to provide a good chunk of information to a user at the outset of the first conversation. Currently, what we've written is about 562 characters. For some of our users, this gets broken up into chunks of 160 characters that do not necessarily show up in their SMS app in the right order.

To account for this, we're trying to break our message down into 160 character or less distinct messages that each send one-after-the-other.

However, my teammates and I are currently unsure how to accomplish this. Our application is currently written to provide a twiml response for each message that is received from a user. I've been unable to find a way to create a twiml response that indicates a number of consecutive messages, and the theoretical solutions we've come up with feel hacky and flawed.

To demonstrate, currently our code looks like this. As you can see, when a new user sends in the keyword "start" we join 4 messages together in one long text response. However we'd like each message to be sent individually, one after the other, about a second or two apart.

```
    case @body
    when "start"
      if !!@user
        CreateMessage::SubscriptionMessage.triage_subscribable_type(!!@user)
      else
        [
          CreateMessage::AlphaMessage.personalized_welcome(@conversation.from, true),
          CreateMessage::SubscriptionMessage.introduce_bcd,
          CreateMessage::SubscriptionMessage.for_example,
          CreateMessage::SubscriptionMessage.intvite_to_start
        ].join("\n\n")
      end
```

We'd like to avoid creating a background worker/cron job, if possible - but welcome any and all suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more on how to design synchronous(webhook response) vs asynchronous responses/messages. I have not used twiml but the concepts are same.

If you don't want to use a background job, then send fir N-1 messages using API with time delay in between, and the last message as response.

If you are OK with using background jobs, then send 1st message as response and queue a job for sending the remaining messages using API.